# Iterating through json api dictionary field

Tags: json, ajax, api

Is there a way to iterate through an api using an ajax "GET" method on a given url? I have a series of ranks with data contained therein and I'm trying to use a for loop to access the data. The api is structured as such:

```
{
   "top_5":{
      "rank_1": [
         123,
         456,
      ],
      "rank_2": [
         123,
         456,
      ],
   }
}
```

And my ajax call in the html is written like so:

```
<script>
for (let i = 1; i < 6; i++) {
    $.ajax({
        method: "GET",
        url: '/refunds/api',
        success: function(data){
            metric = data.top_5.rank_1          
            myDiv = 'myChart'+i        
            barChart()        
        },
        error: function(error_data){
            console.log("error")
            console.log(error_data)
        }
    })
}
</script>
```

The loop works for generating a unique div id, but now I'm stuck trying to engineer the `metric` variable so that is dynamic and iterates to `data.top_5.rank_i+1` on each loop. I think I need to use the map function, but I'm not sure how'd I'd implement it. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: can't you just do `metric = data.top_5["rank_"+i]` ?

Comment: also it seems you are doing 6 api calls when you could do 1 and just have the for loop within the `success` function. something like `$.ajax({method, url, success: function(data){ for (let i = 1; i < 6; i++) { metric = data.top_5... etc.`

Comment: brilliant! I was missing the [] argument for rank. I tried `...top_5."rank_"+i`. Your solution worked like a charm and I nested the api call in the function as well so it's only firing once. Much appreciated Matthias.

Comment: I've posted my comment as an answer, glad it helped. Please accept my answer :))

Comment: Done. And thanks again for your help! Both with iterating through the api and with the explanation on how to slice through a dictionary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe

```
metric = data.top_5["rank_"+i]
```

could work. It's called bracket notation, can be useful when you need to access dicts/objects with variable names.

```
metric = data["top_5"]["rank_"+i]
```

would also work for example.

`metric = data.top_5."rank_"+i`
doesn't work because the interpreter doesn't know what to do with that. For the dot notation it needs it to be typed out like

```
metric = data.top_5.rank_0
```

Additionally I noticed you are making 6 api calls where I belive you can make only 1 api call (should improve performance). This would be the modification for that:

```
<script>
$.ajax({
    method: "GET",
    url: '/refunds/api',
    success: function(data){
        for (let i = 1; i < 6; i++) {
            metric = data.top_5["rank_"+i];
            myDiv = 'myChart'+i;
            barChart();
        }   
    },
    error: function(error_data){
        console.log("error");
        console.log(error_data);
    }
});
</script>
```